# Regex for endpoint

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group, regex-negation

I need to write a regex that takes certain endpoints. Below an example:

INPUT:

```
https://www.pippo.com/tt-tt/vision-guide/kids-vision-eyecare-101
https://www.pippo.com/tt-tt/vision-guide/lenses-205
https://www.pippo.com/tt-tt/vision-guide/kids-eye-exam
https://www.pippo.com/CategoryLanding?storeId=10851&urlRequestType=Base&categoryId=99930171&langId=-1&catalogId=11651
https://www.pippo.com/ee-ee/send-email
https://www.pippo.com/ff-ff/ray-ban/8053672153743
https://www.pippo.com/as-us/vision-guide/progressives
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://www.pippo.com/tt-tt/vision-guide/kids-vision-eyecare-101
https://www.pippo.com/tt-tt/vision-guide/lenses-205
https://www.pippo.com/tt-tt/vision-guide/kids-eye-exam
https://www.pippo.com/ee-ee/send-email
https://www.pippo.com/as-us/vision-guide/progressives
```

I wrote the following regex `^.+[^-][^0-9]+$` but it doesn't work well.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, what are the conditions to get the expected sample output? Kindly do elaborate more on same, thank you.

Comment: How do *you* recognize what is valid and what is not? What is your thought process? What *steps/rules* do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern you use 2 negated character classes at the end `[^-][^0-9]` meaning not `-` and not a digit.

But looking at the expected result, if you want to match all urls that do not end with `/` or `=` followed by only digits.

```
^https?://\S*[/=](?!\d+$)[^/=\s]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://\S*` Match the protocol and optional non whitespace chars
- `[/=]` Match either `=` or
- `(?!\d+$)` Negative lookahead, assert not only digits till end of string
- `[^/=\s]+` Match 1+ chars other than `/` `=` or a whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kOfEJc/1)

Comment: Hi, your regex, however, discards these links for me and should not discard them. An example: https://www.pippo.com/as-us/vision-guide/progressives. Can you help me?

Comment: @user12557498 What is the rule to also match this type of string? Like this? `^https?://\S*[/=](?!\d+$)[^/=]+$` https://regex101.com/r/zH1Kpp/1

Comment: @user12557498 Can you update your question with that url and add the logic for the matches?

Comment: Hi, the edit is done!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
^(?!.*/\d+$)[^?\n]+$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/U7bXKo/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^?\n]+                  any character except: '?', '\n' (newline)
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```